# Does someone implement Jaeger with Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, jaeger

We are re-building our software platform using a microservice architecture approach.

Most of it using **`Spring Boot`** libraries, and for our entry points we are using *Spring Cloud Gateway* which can be easily integrated with **`Jaeger`** to have tracing in the platform.

We do that using the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And it is working pretty well, we can see the trace on the **`Jaeger UI`** web console.

The problem now is how to send the tracking information to the next inner service in the platform to have every service correlated.

Any ideas?

**We have tried** to inject the tracking information as HTML Headers using a **`GlobalFilter`** but it is using the incoming request and we need to put them on the downstream request... any clue on how to override **`HTTPClient`** used underneath.

```java
@Bean
@Order(-1)
public GlobalFilter tracingFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

        Tracer tracer = TracerResolver.resolveTracer();
        Span span = tracer.buildSpan(request.getMethod().toString())
                .withTag(Tags.SPAN_KIND.getKey(), Tags.SPAN_KIND_CLIENT)
                .start();

        Tags.HTTP_URL.set(span, request.getURI().toString());
        Tags.HTTP_METHOD.set(span, request.getMethod().toString());
        if (request.getURI().getPort() != -1) {
            Tags.PEER_PORT.set(span, request.getURI().getPort());
        }

        ServerHttpRequest.Builder requestBuilder = request.mutate();

        tracer.inject(span.context(), Format.Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, new RequestBuilderCarrier(requestBuilder));

        ...

        }));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

our solution:

Upstream filter implements org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.headers.HttpHeadersFilter

```
exchange.getAttributes().put('your_key_here', value);
```

Downstream filter implements org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.headers.HttpHeadersFilter

```
Object storedValue = exchange.getAttribute('your_key_here'); // NOTE can be null
```

and register them via Spring Java configuration(@Bean)